# ASP:Panel re-positioning

Tags: css, asp.net, user-interface

I have 4 panels in my page. At a time (depending on certain conditions ) either 1,2,3 or all 4 panels are displayed. I want the panels to re-align themselves so that there is no empty space for the panels which are not present.

To make the question more clear I have linked pictorial representations of the above :
 If all panels are visible then it will look like this : http://ibin.co/1zrkoFfExnRZ

If suppose Pannel 3 is hidden it will look like this : http://ibin.co/1zs6YimuLQzU

(As you can clearly see in the image , the space initially occupied by Panel 3 is now occupied by Panel 4 i.e The space is not left empty)

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding:

```
.panel1, .panel2, .panel3, .panel4 {
   width:50%;
   float:left;}
```

to your panels should work perfectly fine.

You can see it in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/e2bf7jq2/)**. Add `display:none`to any panel to check the re-align.

Comment: As I understood correctly he wants to leave the space of panel3 blank and let panel4 stay at its position. Now panel4 is shifter towards panel3

Comment: he said: " I want the panels to re-align themselves so that there is no empty space for the panels which are not present.". Don't scare me making me think my english is even worse than I thought :)

Comment: Haha indeed, I think I was a bit confused by the message! haha I am sorry! +1 for your solution.

Comment: Thank you :) And no,your English isn't bad :P :D :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily been done by using css floating and having a fixed width and height:

```
<h2> All visible </h2>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block1">Block 1</div>
    <div class="block2">Block 2</div>
    <div class="block3">Block 3</div>
    <div class="block4">Block 4</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<h2> Three visible </h2>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block1">Block 1</div>
    <div class="block2">Block 2</div>
    <div class="block4">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width:440px;
    height:240px;
}
.block1, .block2, .block3, .block4{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:5px solid #000;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.clear{clear:both;}

.block4{float:right}
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/w9jcfr6g/1/